# Simplify the way to implement user selection

Tags: python

I'd like to let user select the order of the list over command prompt. For example, I provide a list including 3 kinds of foods then user can decide what they want for breakfast, lunch, and dinner based on the order.

Below is my code but I think it is bad flexibility. If I append more items to list, I need to rewrite the loop. Is there simple way to implement?

Thank you.

```
import os
from msvcrt import getch

def user_select_order(items, order):
  for i in range(2):
    os.system('cls')
    print(f'Select {order[i]}:')
    for j in range(3):
      if items[j] in order:
        print(f'\t{items[j]} - selected')
      else:
        print(f'\t{items[j]} - Press [{j+1}]')
    while True:
      ch = getch().decode('utf-8')
      if ch in ('1', '2', '3'):
        if items[int(ch)-1] not in order:
          order[i] = items[int(ch)-1]
          break
  for item in items:
    if item not in order:
      order[-1] = item
      break
  os.system('cls')
  return order

items = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']
order = ['Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Dinner']
print(user_select_order(items, order))
```

Comment: what is `getch()` ?

Comment: @azro it is "from msvcrt import getch"

Comment: I saw ... but that doesn't tell me what it is, so i ask again, what it is ?

Comment: @azro sorry my mistake. It can catch user input but not displayed on the screen. Please refer to https://pypi.org/project/getch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to handle differnet size of data, your code should not use constant value, but only value from the parameters, such as their length

- Replace `range(2)` by `range(len(items) - 1)`
- Replace `for j in range(3)` by `for idx, item in enumerate(items)` to get both the item and its index
- Replace `('1', '2', '3')` by `map(str, range(1, len(items) + 1))`

  - `len(items) + 1` is `4` in this case
  - `range(1, len(items) + 1)` is `1,2,3`
  - `map(str, range(1, len(items) + 1))` is `'1', '2', '3'`

I also put the both `if` in the same with an `and`. And finally for filling the missing item, I'd suggest something using `set` operation, you get the set of initial items, you remove the ones that are in `order` and you got the missing ones (then get the first, which is the only one)

```
def user_select_order(items, order):
    assert len(items) == len(order)
    for i in range(len(items) - 1):
        os.system('cls')
        print(f'Select {order[i]}:')
        for idx, item in enumerate(items):
            if item in order:
                print(f'\t{item} - selected')
            else:
                print(f'\t{item} - Press [{idx + 1}]')
        while True:
            ch = getch().decode('utf-8')
            if ch in map(str, range(1, len(items) + 1)) and items[int(ch) - 1] not in order:
                order[i] = items[int(ch) - 1]
                break

    missing_items = list(set(items) - set(order))
    order[-1] = missing_items[0]
    os.system('cls')
    return order
```